# solo si se tiene este certificado que lo indique

Tags: significado-en-contexto

No entiendo muy bien la frase “[solo si se tiene este certificado que lo indique](https://loentiendo.com/certificado-emigrante-retornado/)” en “el hecho de haber vuelto a residir no hace que se tenga la consideración de emigrante retornado: solo si se tiene este certificado que lo indique”. Creo que “se tiene este certificado” significa “posee este certificado” en este contexto, pero no entiendo por qué luego dice “que lo indique”. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a entenderlo mejor? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: "que lo indique" es una forma indirecta de hacer referencia a la primera parte de la sentencia. En conjunto lo puedes interpretar como: "Sólo si tienes el certificado que indique que eres un emigrante retornado, puedes decir que eres un emigrante retornado". Pudes ver que la frase se vuelve redundante. Aparentemente debes presentarte ante alguna entidad de migración y consultar si hay alguna forma de obtener dicho certificado.

Comment: solo si se tiene este certificado= solo si **uno** tiene este certificado

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que usan redundancia para que no quede duda

Si solo dices "“solo si se tiene este certificado" tu puedes (suena tonto lo se) ensenar un certificado de cocina, o un certificado que sabes manejar automovil o un certificado de buena conducta.

Cuando refuerzas con "que lo indique" haces incapie que el certificado debe indicar que (eres emigrante retornado)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!